# Print range of positive integers ascending and reverse order - Python

Tags: python, range, reverse

I'd like to print the output as a palindromic triangle of positive numbers (without 0's), either through user input `int(input())`:

```
for i in range(1,int(input())+1):
   print(*range(1, i+1),(*range(i-1, -1, -1)))
```

or as fixed range like this:

```
for n in range(1,5):
  print(*range(1, n+1),(*range(n-1, -1, -1))
```

I can get the latter to work as far as this, but I'd like it without the 0's. Two additional issues: 1) Will user input of 5 be the same as hard coded 5 in the range? 2) How to get the 5 included in output? Any idea how this can be done? Thanks in advance.

```
1 0
1 2 1 0
1 2 3 2 1 0
1 2 3 4 3 2 1 0
```

Comment: In case anyone is wondering about the syntax and the purpose of the asterisk, the Python docs explain: "If the syntax *expression appears in the function call, expression must evaluate to an iterable." https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your indexing is just ever so slightly off:

```
user_range = int(input("Desired limit : ")) + 1

for n in range(1, user_range):
  print(*range(1, n+1),(*range(n-1, 0, -1)))
```

output:

```
1
1 2 1
1 2 3 2 1
1 2 3 4 3 2 1
1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1
```

Comment: Very cool, thank you. Can you elaborate on the arguments passed in the print's second range: it seems that zero made the difference.

Comment: np! In Python when you have `range(x, y, z)` or `range(x, y)`, the ending point `y` of the iterator is not inclusive. If set to `-1` the iteration will stop at 0, and if set to `0`, the iteration will stop at `1` :)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? Rather than hardcoding 5 we are asking the input from the user. And a slight modification to the indexing as well.

```
for i in range(1,int(input("Enter number : "))+1):
    print(*range(1,i+1), *range(i-1,-1,-1))
```

Ouput:

```
Enter number : 7
1 0
1 2 1 0
1 2 3 2 1 0
1 2 3 4 3 2 1 0
1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1 0
1 2 3 4 5 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
```

Comment: Thank you, yes ideally prefer to have user input, but keep the range in positive numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Nice fancy work with those ranges and splats. I don't see anything wrong with slicing.

```
for n in range(1,5):
  print(*range(1, n+1), *range(n-1, -1, -1)[:-1])
```

Somebody else said this and it seems to work the same:

```
for n in range(1,5):
  print(*range(1, n+1), *range(n-1, 0, -1))
```

Comment: Thanks, I missed that slicing part, if you could elaborate.

Comment: In my example: `*range(n-1, -1, -1)[:-1]` simply cuts off everything after the `-1`nth  (the last) position in the range.

Comment: Thanks. I see that the results only get to 4 even though the *range(1,n+1) should make it all inclusive, and so the user input is the ideal way to go.